# Неявное приведение типа при конкантенации в PHP

Tags: php

Почему в **PHP**  при конкатенации, `false`, равняется `null`, и как сделать так, что бы `false`, выводился как `0`? Самое интересное то что `0`, выводится как `0`, а `false`, `нет`, хоят `true` выводится как `1`.

```
$test = false;
echo "Это нуль - ".$test;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что в строковом типе `false` - это пустая строка. Преобразуйте ее сначала в численный тип, например функцией `intval()`:

```
$test = false;
echo "Это нуль - ".intval($test);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо Вам за ответ.